# Vistual Studio C++ program exiting with code -1073741819 when trying to use Python.h

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio

I asked for Poe AI to write me some basic code using the Python / C API. I followed its instructions for setup, built the project, ran the code, and it exited with -1073741819.

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Python.h>

int main() {
    Py_Initialize();  // Initialize the Python interpreter

    // Execute a simple Python expression
    PyObject* result = PyRun_String("2 + 2", Py_eval_input, PyEval_GetGlobals(), PyEval_GetGlobals());

    // Check if execution was successful
    if (result == nullptr) {
        PyErr_Print();  // Print any Python errors
        return 1;
    }

    // Extract the result as a C integer
    int value = PyLong_AsLong(result);
    Py_DECREF(result);  // Cleanup

    // Print the result
    printf("Result: %d\n", value);

    Py_Finalize();  // Clean up the Python interpreter
    return 0;
}
```

The steps I followed from Poe AI were as follows:

1. Install Python - which I already had installed (version 3.11). I ran `--version` in the command line to make sure. I have been able to use it in the command line for a long time, pip install packages, etc.
2. Install Visual Studio - I had 2019 installed. I uninstalled it, downloaded the new one (Visual Studio 2022; waited for an hour to download every package available in the installer), rebooted my computer, and continued.
3. Set up Environment Variables (under System Variables, not User Variables) -

   - I created the "PYTHON_HOME" variable, because I didn't have one - Python was on the Path variable; I took it out and replaced it with "PYTHON_HOME" and still works like usual.
   - Add the following two entries to the "Variable value" field:

     - %PYTHON_HOME%
     - %PYTHON_HOME%\Scripts
   - Python still works for me.
4. Configure Visual Studio: Open Visual Studio and create a new C project or open an existing one. To configure the project to compile with Python.h, follow these steps:

   - Right-click on the project in the Solution Explorer and select "Properties".
   - In the "Configuration Properties" section, select "C/C++".
   - In the "Additional Include Directories" field, add the following path:

     - %PYTHON_HOME%\include.
   - Click "Apply" to save the changes.
5. Compile and Link: Now you can write your C code that includes Python.h and compile it using Visual Studio. Make sure to include #include <Python.h> at the beginning of your C file. When compiling, ensure that you link against the Python library. To do this, add the Python library path to the linker settings.

   - In the project properties, go to "Configuration Properties" -> "Linker" -> "Input".
   - In the "Additional Dependencies" field, add the following entry:

     - %PYTHON_HOME%\libs\python39.lib (replace python39 with your Python version if different).

Doing this solved all the errors that were displayed in the Visual Studio 2022 IDE, yet when I built the project and compiled it, it threw an error in the console -> Can't find python311_d.lib.

So I go back to Poe AI, and it says to resolve this issue I have 1 of 3 options (I will spare you some, reading; I did option 2):

1. Install the correct Python version: Make sure you have the correct version of Python installed on your system. If you are targeting Python 3.11, ensure that you have Python 3.11 installed. You can download the specific Python version you need from the Python website (https://www.python.org/downloads/). Make sure to select the debug version of the Python installer if you require the debug library.
2. Update the project configuration: Open the project properties in Visual Studio and verify that the Python library path and library name are correctly configured. Follow these steps:

   - Right-click on the project in the Solution Explorer and select "Properties".
   - In the "Configuration Properties" section, select "Linker" -> "Input".
   - Check the "Additional Dependencies" field and ensure that it specifies the correct library name for your Python version. For Python 3.11, it should be python311_d.lib for the debug version or python311.lib for the release version.
   - If the library name is incorrect, update it accordingly.
   - Also, double-check the "Additional Library Directories" field and ensure it points to the correct directory where the Python library is located.
3. Switch to a different Python version: If you don't specifically require Python 3.11, you can consider using a different Python version that is already installed on your system. Update your project configuration to use the correct library name and library directories for the Python version you have installed.

When I did option 2, it fixed the error in the console, so I ran the code in VS, which then returned -1073741819, and press any key to continue. Poe AI has not been helpful at all. I've deleted the project and tried the same steps again, with the same results (I'm not crazy /stupid enough to do it for a 3rd time whilst expecting different results). Does anyone on this planet (or forum) know why this happening to me?

Comment: That value translates to 0xc0000005 or STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION. Run the program in a debugger and see where the crash is happening.

Comment: Please don't follow a possibly hallucinating AI. Read [the actual Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/index.html) instead. Like [the section about the C (and C++) interface](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/index.html). Also note that there are a few C++ libraries available that will simplify connection between C++ and Python quite considerably.

Comment: In general, when you see a crazy number like -1073741819 convert it to hex and see if it's more recognizable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've gone and created a project form your instructions (I did not use python C-API on this PC before, but I did have VS2019 and Python 3.9 already installed).

The problem I encountered was that `PyEval_GetGlobals()` was returning NULL.
Apparently is such a case one needs to call `PyImport_AddModule("__main__")`.

Here is the change I did to your code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Python.h>

int main()
{
    Py_Initialize();  // Initialize the Python interpreter

    PyObject* d = PyModule_GetDict(PyImport_AddModule("__main__"));
    // Execute a simple Python expression
    PyObject* result = PyRun_String("2 + 2", Py_eval_input, d, d);

    // Check if execution was successful
    if (result == nullptr) {
        PyErr_Print();  // Print any Python errors
        return 1;
    }

    // Extract the result as a C integer
    int value = PyLong_AsLong(result);
    Py_DECREF(result);  // Cleanup

    // Print the result
    printf("Result: %d\n", value);

    Py_Finalize();  // Clean up the Python interpreter
    return 0;
}
```

This ran ok for me and printed `Result: 4` in the console.

Make sure the PYTHON_HOME variable contains the path to your python installation:
e.g. calling in a console `echo %PYTHON_HOME%` returns `c:\Python\Python39` in my case. I mention this, because this part in your instructions really confused me:

> Add the following two entries to the "Variable value" field:
>
> ```
> %PYTHON_HOME%
> %PYTHON_HOME%\Scripts
> ```

Note: I'm using Visual Studio Community 2019 and Python39 and ran the project in 'Release' and 'x64' mode.

Comment: Yes, I understand the confusion, seeing that that's not actually what happened. I added %PYTHON_HOME% to the Variable Value field, and then added %PYTHON_HOME% AND %PYTHON_HOME%\Scripts to the Path variable, my bad. I actually didn't need to  do the line where d is declared. This worked for me:
`    PyObject* globals = PyDict_New();
    PyObject* locals = PyDict_New();

    // Execute a simple Python expression
    auto python_str = "4**4";
    PyObject* result = PyRun_String(python_str, Py_eval_input, globals, globals);`, however I don't like it because locals should be somewhere...

Comment: but where? In place of the first globals or the second? Your solution does the same thing mine does.

Comment: All that I'm trying to say is that if you look at the code I supplied, `PyEval_GetGlobals()` is not stored in a variable, but yours is. Mine doesn't run, yours does. When I made that change (store `PyEval_GetGlobals()` in a variable and then use that variable for the call) it worked.

Comment: @Shmack Re: why does PyDict_New() work? Remember what I said: PyEval_GetGlobals() returns NULL; my code avoided that by loading the python __main__ module, then getting a valid Dictionary as a result of that operation. PyDict_New() which you used also creates a valid Dictionary which is empty. For now a valid Dictionary, even if it is empty, seems to be sufficient to run the string sent to python. It may be that once you supply a longer program it is not enough.